# Occasional problems with CDO (which are resolved by reseting windows)

Tags: vb6, cdo.message

I'm using the following code to send emails.
Sometimes (once or twice a month) emails are not being sent, but I don't get an error, it's the receiver who informs me that he didn't receive the email.
If I turn off the computer and turn it on again, there is no problem.

Any ideas?

The same happens in Windows 10 or Windows 7...

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

objMessage.Subject = sMailSubject
objMessage.From = Chr$(34) & "=?" & "ISO-8859-7" & "?" & "B" & "?" & Base64Str(sMailFrom) & "?=" & Chr$(34) & " <" & sEmailUser & ">"
objMessage.To = ToEmail
objMessage.ReplyTo = sReplyAddres
objMessage.TexsMailBody = sMailBody
objMessage.BodyPart.Charset = "ISO-8859-7"
If sPathAttahcment <> "" And Dir(sPathAttahcment) <> "" Then objMessage.AddAttachment sPathAttahcment

With objMessage.Configuration.Fields
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = cdoSendUsingPort
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = sSMTPserver
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = sEmailUser
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = sEmailPass 
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = sSMTPport
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 10
    .Update
End With

objMessage.Send

set objMessage = Nothing
```

Comment: forgot to mention, I use gmail and yahoo, same problem

Comment: If you don't reboot the server, will the problem systematically occur?

Comment: yes, I can only send emails after reboot. I tried with many computers and i thought that maybe it has to do with my code, since i don't have problem with thunderbird.

Comment: You should record log infos in a flat file that trace all the steps of your code, including variable values. Wait for the problem to occurs and analyze your log file. Maybe you should see common points with problematic mails or even that everything worked fine with your code because the problem could  be related to the mail provider.